# Can I add RSS-less websites on Feedly or other RSS-Reader?

Tags: rss

I am a huge fan of RSS.I am currently using Feedly as my default RSS Reader.I have a question though that I am unable to find the answer.How can I follow a website that does not provide RSS Feeds?I have tried several addons on firefox or extensions on chrome that automatically detect RSS when I am visiting a website,therefore with one-click I can add that website on Feedly.In addition I have searched through the internet to create manually an RSS Feed,when a website does not provide one,but it seems there is not a free way to do it,or if I try an online 'RSS Creator' (like page2rss and more) most of the times they are not working (either can't find the RSS of a website or create an invalid RSS).However,I didn't give up,so I was desperately seeking a way,to find the RSS Feed via the 'source code' of a website.Unfortunately,that only works for Youtube Channels and not for other websites.Is there a way via those actions to 'follow' another website?
I have found a way to 'detect changes' of Feed-less websites using update-scanner addon on firefox and page monitor on chrome.But,all I want to do is put those webpages in one app/website (like Feedly) so that I can follow them whether I am using my pc,or iphone/ipad (iOS),or tablet (android),or another user's pc/laptop.Any suggestions?Keep in mind that  iOS devices don't support extensions.If I confused you,visit this link and you'll understand exactly what I am looking for.
http://googlereader.blogspot.gr/2010/01/follow-changes-to-any-website.html
The only drawback is that googleReader does not exist anymore!Do you know another RSS Reader that support this feature (like Feedly,the Old Reader etc) ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A simple but basic solution is Page2Rss.com. You put the URL of the page. One's a day, the service crawl the page and generate an item for all what's new.

Feed43.com does a much better job, even its free version. You have to elaborate rules of extraction from the HTML code.

Feedity is much (much) more interactive, bit commercial.

Comment: Page2RSS is nor working properly.Do you know an RSS Reader that supports the feature of GoogleReader I mentioned at my question?